# Why is my overloaded subscript operator for rvalue not called

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have looked up and down stack overflow and keep finding the same examples which I think I have implemented. I am trying to implement an associative array. I know there is std::map but I'd like to do the implementation myself for better control and better understanding.

I have overloaded the subscript operator for lvalue and rvalue. However in my code only the method for the lvalue is called and I can't find where I am mistaken. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?
Here's my code for the class. For now, it's not supposed to be efficient, just working would make me happy:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class AssocArray {

private:
    size_t _arraySize = 0;
    K *_keyArray = nullptr;
    V *_valueArray = nullptr;

    void expandValueArray() {
        auto newValueArray = new V[_arraySize];
        // copy old values
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _arraySize - 1; ++i)
            newValueArray[i] = _valueArray[i];
        if (_valueArray)
            delete[] _valueArray;
        _valueArray = newValueArray;
    }

    void appendToKeyArray(K key) {
        auto newKeyArray = new K[_arraySize];
        // copy old keys
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _arraySize - 1; ++i)
            newKeyArray[i] = _keyArray[i];
        newKeyArray[_arraySize - 1] = key;
        delete[] _keyArray;
        _keyArray = newKeyArray;
    }

    bool keyExists(K key) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _arraySize; ++i)
            if (_keyArray[i] == key)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    size_t getExistingKeyIndex(K key) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _arraySize; ++i)
            if (_keyArray[i] == key)
                return i;
    }

public:
    ~AssocArray() {
        delete[] _valueArray;
        delete[] _keyArray;
    }

    V operator[](K key) const {
        if (keyExists(key))
            return _valueArray[getExistingKeyIndex(key)];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("Key does not exist");
    }

    V &operator[](K key) {
        if (keyExists(key))
            return _valueArray[getExistingKeyIndex(key)];

        // key does not exist
        ++_arraySize;
        appendToKeyArray(key);
        expandValueArray();
        return _valueArray[_arraySize - 1];
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "Content of AssocArray:" << std::endl;
        if (!_arraySize) std::cout << "none" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < _arraySize; ++i) {
            std::cout << "[" << _keyArray[i] << "] => " << _valueArray[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

and here is how I call it and produce the undesired behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AssocArray.h"

int main() {
       AssocArray<std::string, std::string> assocArray;

        (assocArray)["Toni"] = "seven";
        (assocArray)["Sam"] = "five";
        std::cout << "assocArray before lookup of non existing key:" << std::endl << std::endl;
        assocArray.print();
        // FixMe: appends key to assocArray, but shouldn't
        std::cout << std::endl << "lookup of non existing key:" << std::endl;
        auto key = "Megan";
        std::cout << "[" << key << "] => " << assocArray[key] << std::endl << std::endl;

        std::cout << "assocArray after lookup of non existing key:" << std::endl;
        assocArray.print();
}
```

The output is this (see that Megan is added to the array where it shouldn't be):

```
assocArray before lookup of non existing key:

Content of AssocArray:
[Toni] => seven
[Sam] => five

lookup of non existing key:
[Megan] => 

assocArray after lookup of non existing key:
Content of AssocArray:
[Toni] => seven
[Sam] => five
[Megan] =>
```

Why don't I get an exception? Why is the overloaded method for the lvalue called here?
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You didn't implement overloads based on l-value/r-value. You implemented overloads based on constness of the `AssocArray` object. Your object is non-const, so always the non-const overload will be used. What exactly did you want to achieve? Distinguish based on l-value/r-value of the `key` parameter or l-value/r-value of the AssocArray object itself?

Comment: Some side notes: I wouldn't increment the array with *every* newly added element, rather have two values `size` and `capacity`, doubling the latter on need: `if(size == capacity) { capacity *= 2; /* allocate new array and copy */ }`. I'd avoid, too, two separate arrays, instead rather have one single array of `std::pair<K, V>` (or your own struct, if you prefer). `if(exists()) { get(); }` iterates twice over the array, which is pretty inefficient. You should profit from the index already found by some means (returning `std::pair<bool, size_t>`, having an output parameter `&size_t index`, ...).

Comment: Perhaps this will helpful to understand the differences: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9J4Lbrpam0aHU99t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The issue in question

Turns out, you're asking the wrong question. You're having a logic problem, which in this particular case has nothing to do with ref-qualification of the member function. In your code, I can see no trace of any use where the `AssocArray` is being an rvalue *(on which we want to call `operator[]`)*.

To have a viable solution, I would suggest you to look toward two following approaches:

1. Recall, that when we subscript `std::map` and there's no such key yet, the `std::map` will add such key in with default value. This is exactly what's happening in your current implemenation. To not insert an element every time we want to fetch one, we have `at()`. So, you can just add equivalent `at()` member function, which may throw or just silently return some default value, denoting there's no such element.
2. You can throw on every invalid fetch. If the subscript is done on a valid key, then return a `&` to the according `mapped_type` (the value mapped to the key), which you can read/modify.

#### Ref-qualifiers

You should consider the difference:

```
V& operator[]();
V operator[]() const;
```

Vs.

```
// An example approach to return types
// You should look mainly on the ref-qualifiers here
V& operator[]() &&; // called on rvalues
const V& operator[]() const&; // called on const and non-const lvalues
```

In your class, you have one `[]` that returns a copy of a fetched element, and another `[]` that is called on a `const` instance and returns a reference. There are no operators which distinct whether they are called on an rvalue or lvalue.

*For more information on ref-qualifiers, you may refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#qualified_member_functions).*

Comment: You wouldn't want to allow editing values on `const` maps, so the reference returned should rather be `const` as well on second operator.

Comment: @Aconcagua you mean the latest edit? The `const V& operator[]() const&;`?

Comment: Thanks @rawrex. Unfortunately I don't understand what you're suggesting.
```V&``` means the function returns a reference. What do the ```&```after the function declaration mean?

Comment: @donnerluetjen that's what ref-qualifiers are. You should check the supplied link and if needed use a search engine. After you will get familiar with what those are *(spoiler: these just specify the type of `this`)*, you will get what the answer is about.

Comment: @rawrex Sorry for that. I didn't see the link.
If I change my signatures to use ref-qualifiers the result is the same, however.
If I use const in my lvalue member's signature, then any assignment in the function becomes illegal acc. to my compiler.

Comment: @donnerluetjen I will look into the class' implementation more thoroughly in a few minutes.

Comment: @donnerluetjen check the edit. Tried to address the global issue here.

Comment: @rawrex thank you for taking this time to provide all the information. I'll mark this as an answer. Although I find that if that is the only solution then what's the point of using the subscript operator overload. I might just implement a getter (```at()```) and setter. I assumed that if I don't assign anything to a reference than the reference is a rvalue. Apparently that's not the case.
Is there a way to let the compiler know that I am expecting a rvalue in my call?

Comment: @donnerluetjen first thing to note, the operator may be used implicitly, unlike a named function (now I can't recall any case where the `operator[]` is used implicitly, but still). The ref-qualification of a member function allows us to overload based on lvalue/rvalue qualification of the object on which we invoke the method. The `const`ness qualification of an object is a thing on its own, too. In the end, as with the `std::map` it is convenient to have some implicit logic (subscript) and some explicit logic (`at()`).

Comment: @donnerluetjen hey! I've come up with one use case where it is quite logical to have almost the same definitions as in your original question. Will try to edit it all in soon enough.